# How to replace paragraph with image?

Tags: html, css

Well, this sounds simple, but I am stuck here.

```
<div id="newPage">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam in nisl turpis, eget      faucibus diam. Fusce id magna quis enim elementum imperdiet. Proin sit amet purus lacus, id placerat nulla. Quisque interdum, velit eget tempor aliquet, lorem neque pharetra nisi, a .</p>
    <img src="images/layout/nokia.gif" />
</div>
```

Now, I want to put image on the right side and paragraph on the left side. (Note: It must be inside single div tag).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap the `img` and the `p` tag around, and then apply a `float:right` to the `img`.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/XpnQJ/1/ for details - I've added a width and height to the image as a demo

Answer (score 2):

you can use the css property `float`.
check [this page](http://jsfiddle.net/2hamed/weBdW/).

Answer (score 0):

Have `<p>` tag after the image tag and give align property to image tag, like this.

```
<img src="images/layout/nokia.gif" align="right"/>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam
in nisl turpis, eget faucibus diam. Fusce id magna quis enim elementum
imperdiet. Proin sit amet purus lacus, id placerat nulla. Quisque
interdum, velit eget tempor aliquet, lorem neque pharetra nisi, a .
Lorem ipsum dolor      sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam
in nisl turpis, eget faucibus diam. Fusce id magna quis enim elementum</p>
```

Comment: It's aligned right, but can't replace the paragraph. Instead, it is aligned right below the paragraph which is not what I am asking.

Comment: If you give <p> tag after the image tag, image will not come under <p>

Answer (score 0):

```
img { float:right; }
```

You should give float:right to img tag. So, img is align right, p is align left

Answer (score 0):

You can use floats, but with the restriction of one div you will have to specify a width for the text that ensures the width of the page remains within the browser window (or the image will wrap below the text)  Optionally you can specify an overall width for the page and this will stop the wrap:

```
<style>
    #newPage {float: left; width: 800px;} /* Optional */
    #newPage p {float: left; width: 720px;}
    #newPage img {float: right;}
</style>

<div id="newPage">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam in nisl turpis, eget      faucibus diam. Fusce id magna quis enim elementum imperdiet. Proin sit amet purus lacus, id placerat nulla. Quisque interdum, velit eget tempor aliquet, lorem neque pharetra nisi, a.</p>
<img src="images/layout/nokia.gif"/>
</div>
```